# Why can I call getline without using std::getline?

Tags: c++, namespaces, getline

I am following the C++ Primer book and trying out all the code examples.
I am intrigued by this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string line;
    while (getline(cin,line))
        cout << line << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Before compiling this code I was guessing that the compilation would fail, since I am not using

```
while (std::getline(cin,line))
```

Why is getline in the global namespace?
As I understand, this should only happen if I used

```
namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::getline;
```

I am using g++ version 4.8.2 on Linux Mint Debian Edition.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Unqualified lookup (what you are doing when you just call `getline()` instead of `std::getline()`) will start by trying to do normal name lookup for `getline`. It will find nothing - you have no variables, functions, classes, etc. in scope with that name.

We will then look in the "associated namespaces" of each of the arguments. In this case, the arguments are `cin` and `line`, which have types `std::istream` and `std::string` respectively, so their associated namespaces are both `std`. We then redo lookup within namespace `std` for `getline` and find `std::getline`.

There are many more details, I encourage you to read the reference I cited. This process is additionally known as Koenig lookup.

Comment: Is this standard c++?

Comment: @kalkanistovinko Yes it is.

Answer (score 7):

Since `std::getline()` for `std::string` [is defined in the  header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) I would have to say that [Argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is coming into play.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `getline(cin, line)`, it is equivalent to using `getline(std::cin, line)` since you have the line:

```
using std::cin;
```

Using Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL), the compiler is able to resolve that function call to `std::getline(std::cin, line)`. You can read more about ADL at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl.